# Convert string to ISODate in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, date

I am new to MongoDB and I am stuck on the String to Date conversion. In the db the date item is stored in String type as `"date":"2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z"`

I want to group the docs by date and calculate the sum of each day so I have to extract year, month and day from the date string and wipe off the hrs, mins and seconds. I have tried multiple way but they either return a date type of 1970-01-01 or the current date.

Moreover, I want to convert the following mongo query into python code, which get me the same problem, I am not able to call a javascript function in python, and the `datetime` can not parse the mongo syntax `$date` either.

I have tried:

```
new Date("2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z")
new Date(Date.parse("2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z"))
etc...
```

I am perfectly find if the string is given in Javascript or in Python, I know more than one way to parse it. However I have no idea about how to do it in MongoDB query.

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
                    {
                        //somthing
                    },
                    { 
                        '$group':{
                            '_id':{ 
                                'month':  (new Date(Date.parse('$approTime'))).getMonth(), 
                                'day': (new Date(Date.parse('$approTime'))).getDate(), 
                                'year':  (new Date(Date.parse('$approTime'))).getFullYear(),
                                'countries':'$countries'
                            },
                             'count': {'$sum':1}

                    }
                }
])
```

Comment: Why are you storing date as a String?

Comment: @Buzz  Someone else did, I have to get the data without changing the production environment at this moment

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti The reason I store it as a string is because I don't want to be converted to  UTC time. I need to group on week numbers, so when I do that in UTC, (I am AEST (sydney) time) something that was on Sptember 1st at 6:00am would be August 31 somewhere in the afternoon. That could just mean it is counted the previous week number. I am stuck with Mongo 2.6 right now, so there are not many options beside extracting the AEST Weeknumber in the import and store it separately

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can be assured of the format of the input date string AND you are just trying to get a count of unique YYYYMMDD, then just $project the substring and group on it:

```
var data = [
        { "name": "buzz", "d1": "2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z"},
        { "name": "matt", "d1": "2018-06-16T17:50:30.081Z"},
        { "name": "bob", "d1": "2018-06-16T17:50:30.081Z"},
        { "name": "corn", "d1": "2019-06-16T17:50:30.081Z"},
      ];

db.foo.drop();
db.foo.insert(data);

db.foo.aggregate([
     { "$project": {
         "xd": { "$substr": [ "$d1", 0, 10 ]}
         }
 },
 { "$group": {
             "_id": "$xd",
             "n": {$sum: 1}
         }
     }
              ]);

{ "_id" : "2019-06-16", "n" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "2018-06-16", "n" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "2015-06-16", "n" : 1 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I should have remembered using `$project` earlier. after aggregation I just use `forEach` and build a `ISODate` by substrings of the date string

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Mongo 4.0`, you can use [`"$toDate"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) to convert a string to a date:

```js
// { name: "buzz", d1: "2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z" }
// { name: "matt", d1: "2018-06-16T17:50:30.081Z" }
// { name: "bob",  d1: "2018-06-16T17:50:30.081Z" }
// { name: "corn", d1: "2019-06-16T17:50:30.081Z" }
db.collection.aggregate(
  { $group: {
    _id: { $dateToString: { date: { $toDate: "$d1" }, format: "%Y-%m-%d" } },
    n: { $sum: 1 }
  }}
)
// { _id: "2015-06-16", n: 1 }
// { _id: "2018-06-16", n: 2 }
// { _id: "2019-06-16", n: 1 }
```

Within the group stage, this:

- first converts strings (such as `"2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z"`) to date objects (`ISODate("2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z")`) using the [`"$toDate"`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) operator.
- then converts the converted date (such as `ISODate("2015-06-16T17:50:30.081Z")`) back to string (`"2015-06-16"`) but this time with this format `"%Y-%m-%d"`, using the [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) operator.