# MongoDB - Count documents based on if a field has a particular value in group stage

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

**I Wrote an Mysql query like this :**

```
SELECT account_id,date(date_posted) as date_posted,sum(if(message_format = 'e',1,0)) as email_count,sum(if(message_format = 't',1,0)) as 
sms_count,sum(if(message_format = 'p',1,0)) as push_count,sum(if(message_format = 's',1,0)) as slack_count
FROM `track_notifications` GROUP BY date(date_posted), account_id ORDER BY account_id
```

The MySQL result is shown in the below image :

[image]

*I want to get the same as MySQL result in **MongoDB**, I am new to **MongoDB**. How to write this query in MongoDB*

**I tried like this :**

```
db.Datasets.aggregate([{$project:{_id:0,account_id:1,date_posted:1,message_format:{$ifNull:["$message_format",0]}}},{$sort:{"account_id":1}}])
```

**Sample Docs :**

```
_id:ObjectId(“5e8851dc53a883900d9b8e4b”)
account_id:52519
date_posted:”2018-11-19T15:38:52.000Z”
message_format:”t”

_id:ObjectId(“5e8851dc53a883900d9b8e4c”)
account_id:52519
date_posted:”2018-11-19T15:43:01.000Z”
message_format:”e”

_id:ObjectId(“5e8851dc53a883900d9b8e4d”)
account_id:52519
date_posted:”2018-11-19T15:38:51.000Z”
message_format:”e”

_id:ObjectId(“5e8851dc53a883900d9b8e4d”)
account_id:52519
date_posted:”2018-11-19T15:56:22.000Z”
message_format:”s”

_id:ObjectId(“5e8851dc53a883900d9b8e4e”)
account_id:52519
date_posted:”2018-11-19T15:56:22.000Z”
message_format:”p”
```

After a long research & try, I'm  stuck in here `sum(if(message_format = 't',1,0))`, Please help.

Comment: It would be easy if you can provide sample mongodb doc's & required o/p

Comment: I updated the sample MongoDB docs and I need to get the result same as MySQL result. Please give a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below aggregation query :

**Steps :**

1. You would group on `account_id` & converted `date_posted` & have a conditional check on `message_format` field & pass `1` or `0` to `$sum` based on field value, if field is `null` then `0` will be passed, So while grouping docs, if 10 docs have `message_format == e` then 
   `email_count` will be `10` & rest others will be `0`.
2. Then you can add `account_id` & `date_posted` fields extracted from `$_id`.
3. Remove unnecessary `_id` field using project.
4. Sort on `account_id` to order result docs in ascending order.

**Query :**

```
db.track_notifications.aggregate([
      {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            account_id: "$account_id",
            date_posted: {
              $dateToString: { format: "%Y-%m-%d", date: "$date_posted" },
            },
          },
          email_count: {
            $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$message_format", "e"] }, 1, 0] },
          },
          sms_count: { $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$message_format", "t"] }, 1, 0] } },
          push_count: {
            $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$message_format", "p"] }, 1, 0] },
          },
          slack_count: {
            $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$message_format", "s"] }, 1, 0] },
          },
        },
      },
      {
        $addFields: {
          account_id: "$_id.account_id",
          date_posted: "$_id.date_posted",
        },
      },
      { $project: { _id: 0 } },
      { $sort: { account_id: 1 } },
    ]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/hsfruoOgyzJ)

**Ref :** [aggregation-pipeline-operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the field date_posted is in UTC format.
There is no ISODate() in front of the date, it is just like date_posted:”2018-11-19T15:56:22.000Z”. I was getting an error.
"errmsg" : "can't convert from BSON type string to Date".

Comment: Got the Solution from this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30872891/convert-string-to-isodate-in-mongodb/30878727.
Thank You

Comment: @PRUDHVIRAJ : Ok I thought it's an `ISODate()` in DB, anyway as a hint never store dates as string in DB, you'll have less options to work on for future needs, anyway it's working nice :-)